# Is it possible to automatically repeat several executions on NVVP?

Tags: cuda, nvvp

I'm trying to extract some metrics from my application and need to execute it a lot of times and take the mean of the metrics.

I was googling for it but didn't find anything, and nothing here on stackoverflow too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the metrics you need, you may be better off using `nvprof` and scripting it from the command line. You can output in csv format and then visualise in your favourite spreadsheet/chart app.